# Does BlazeMeter plugin (Chrome) direct traffic to external servers - if test is simply saved?

Tags: blazemeter

I am mainly involved in testing internal web applications and it is important that security is considered... I wonder if anyone can tell me definitively whether sensitive data is sent externally or recorded (ie to Blazemeter) with the following scenario?

1. Open Chrome Browser + BlazeMeter account login
2. Record test steps within Blazemeter on internal web app (including logins)
3. Download as .jmx only (so NO LOAD TESTING HROUGH BLAZEMETER)

I could use Fiddler to test this but would be more comfortable to get the definitive answer from you good folks. Thanks in advance. I will test this in Fiddler anyway when my PC is reconfigured correctly and update.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I revisited this... logged a session and can see traffic going to a.blazemeter.com during recording.
When the recording is finished, the session is uploaded to 'http://converter.blazemeter.com/api/converter' (conversion to jmx).
Guess the simple answer is - if you need to keep traffic on site, use local JMeter proxy recorder.